# Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Enum', required: 'char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum'

Tags: java

I thought java.lang.Enum is an enum, but no?

```
void test(Enum e) {
 switch (e) {
  case A: ...
 }
}
```

> Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Enum', required: 'char, byte,
>   short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum'

Comment: show the code snippet that is causing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought `java.lang.Enum` is an `enum`, but no?

No it isn't.

> *"The direct superclass of an `enum` type `E` is `Enum<E>` (§8.1.4). "*. [JLS 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).

However, that doesn't make `Enum` an `enum` class.

Note also that you can't `extend` the class `Enum`:

> *"It is a compile-time error if the *ClassType* names the class `Enum` or any invocation of `Enum` (§8.9)."* [JLS 8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4).

And since `Enum` is `abstract`, you can't directly instantiate the class, or create an "enum class" apart from declaring an `enum` type.   In short `Enum` is a bit special, and of limited direct use.

---

I expect that you encountered this compilation error in a `switch` statement.  A `switch` statement involving enumerations requires a specific `enum` class ... with the specific set of enum constants that you will use in the switch cases.  The class `Enum<E>` is not where the constants are declared.  (So it wouldn't work from a linguistic perspective.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Refer to:

> JLS §14.11 The switch Statement “The type of [the switch] Expression
>   must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer,
>   String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.”

All *enum* types implicitly extend *java.lang.Enum*, but the *enum* is a special reference type, it is not a class by itself, but more like a category of classes that extends from the same base class Enum. Any type declared by the key word "enum" is by itself a **different** class.

The correct way to make this work would be to first create your enum separately, e.g.

```
enum Day
{
  SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

Then provide the enum to your method as parameter like this:

```
public static void printTodaysThought(Day theDay)
```

And use in the switch statement like so:

```
switch (theDay)
    {
      case MONDAY:
      case TUESDAY:
      case WEDNESDAY:
      case THURSDAY:  System.out.println("THURSDAY");
                      break;

      case FRIDAY:    System.out.println("FRIDAY");
                      break;

      case SATURDAY:
      case SUNDAY:    System.out.println("SUNDAY");
                      break;

      default:        System.out.println("What day is it?");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    enum CarType{
    HATCHBACK,SEDAN,SUV
    }
```

To check the based on enum

```
    CarType cartype;

    switch(cartype){
    case HATCHBACK:
     dosomethingfor hatchback;
     break;
    case SEDAN:
     dosomethingfor sedan;
     break;
    case SUV:
     dosomethingfor suv;
     break;
  default:
     do something default;
}
```